# Django REST Framework: Can't update Foreign Key with JSON POST request

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework that stores data from scanners, which are devices which send a JSON POST request to the framework whenever it detects a new scan. The models are as follows:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
       return self.address

class Scanner(models.Model): 
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='scanner')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.location.address + ": " + self.description + " (id=" + str(self.pk) + ")"

class Scan(models.Model):
    scanner = models.ForeignKey(Scanner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='scan')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now())
    def __str__(self):
        if self.scanner != None: 
            return self.scanner.description + ": " + str(self.datetime)
        else: 
            return "None: " + str(self.datetime)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('datetime',)
```

And the serializers are these:

```
class ScanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scan
        fields = ('id', 'scanner', 'datetime')

class ScannerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Scanner 
        fields = ('id', 'location', 'description',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    scans = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Scan.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'scans')

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location 
        fields = ('id', 'address', 'city', 'state','zipcode', 'latitude', 'longitude')
```

If I use the DRF URL to create new Scan and Scanner objects, it works fine. However when I send a JSON request like this:

```
data={"location": "2", "description": "Test scanner"}
```

it fails to create a new object. I believe the problem is referring to Foreign Keys by just their ID. However, when I tried to create nested objects in the framework and send JSON requests that contain the nested objects, it throws an AssertionError saying that I wasn't filling all the fields properly. How do I format a JSON request to create objects with these Foreign Key relations to existing objects?

Comment: Could you please add error that you get on POST request with `{"location": "2", "description": "Test scanner"}` as data.

Comment: It's better to test on DRF browsable api first.

Comment: It says specifically: IntegrityError at /api/scanners/

api_scanner.description may not be NULL. This is after I set the description field in the Scanner model to be null=True, blank=True. When I didn't have null=True, blank=True, it simply said "Description field is required."

Comment: Windsoon, I was testing on the browsable API. That's what I meant when I said "If i use the DRF URL to create new objects, it works fine." I should have clarified that I meant the browsable API.